# How pass a file to a js function in Django?

Tags: javascript, django

I will integrate the [PhylD3](https://phyd3.bits.vib.be/) library in an Django Template.

The css and js are integrated in django static directory.

But i dont really know how process to efficiently load the **xml** file in the template.

## template phyD3.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}


{% block title %} Test {% endblock %}

{%  block content %}


    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/phyd3/phyd3.min.css' %}" />
        <script src="{% static 'js/phyd3/phyd3.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script>
            function load() {
                d3.xml("sample.xml", function(xml) {
                    var tree = phyd3.phyloxml.parse(xml);
                    phyd3.phylogram.build("#phyd3", tree, {});
                });
            };
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="load()">
        <div id="phyd3"></div>
    </body>


 {% endblock %}
```

## view.py

```
def phyd3(request):

    return render(request, 'coregenome/phyD3.html')
```

## error in browser consol

[image]

Comment: Where is the xml file in your project? I would recommend storing it somewhere in the `static` folder and then using the `{% static %}` template tag, just as you are for the CSS and JS.

Comment: @RobinZigmond thank for this tip =)

Answer (score 0):

I put the static tag to simply load the file.

```
    <script>
        function load() {
            d3.xml("{% static 'sample.xml' %}", function(xml) {
                var tree = phyd3.phyloxml.parse(xml);
                phyd3.phylogram.build("#phyd3", tree, {});
            });
        };
    </script>
```